# Problems with curl requests for RESTful API - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am trying to create a RESTful application using Laravel (I am beginner). It is a login-based app with creating a post and creating a comment to a post.(only authenticated users can write a post or comment). I made the functionality to create post and I tested  it with curl request that looks like this:

```
$ curl --data "title=test&body=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post?api_token=dLE6IofaGHmG1CWU6b6jWUE9h4161G8FJ3719CjZkTRbkH4orIvT5aGGNhWt
```

It is working and everything is fine. I also created the routes in api.php for login/logout/register. And I want to test them via curl requests. So I am trying to test it with some requests like:

```
$ curl --data "name=test&email=test@gmail.com&password=test&password_confirmation=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register
```

And they all redirect me to login. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `routes` to ?

Comment: Can you share your register function as well?

Comment: @apokryfos `protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'api_token' => str_random(60),
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }`

Comment: @ElitsaVrancheva can you update the question with that? Also that's the create method, what happens after that?

Comment: @apokryfos In general, the authentication is in-built functionalty that comes with the framework. I just enabled it. I didn't write any code except for adding the line for creating random api_token. It is generally working if you use the interface provided but I want to test it in the command line. But after register the user is logged in.

Comment: @ElitsaVrancheva what concerns me is that the built-in laravel boilerplace for this is for a web based registration. It may not work as well for an API route. Since you're in the starting phases of your project perhaps you can also look into using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) for registration/authentication.

Comment: @apokryfos Ok, thanks, I will check it now and keep you updated. :)

Comment: @аpokryfos Ok, I made the authentication with passport so it is issuing tokents whenever I made such request:
`curl --data "client_id=2&client_secret=6X30BTvJqtPjhsgOmyVjq9DMFTyQU0XItRDHNk3D&grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&password=test" http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token
` 
Firstly, I can't find any information how the registration request should look like then. And when I try to create new post with the request in the question it is redirecting to login again. I try to make the same request changing the api_token parameter to access_token. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

**routes/api.php** does not use the StartSession middleware and since logins use sessions, it will always prompt you to login on each request.

You have a few options

1) move your API routes into **routes/web.php** 
so your API uses sessions.

***This is not the best design however as APIs should be stateless*** to follow good REST design principles, but it will solve your login problem.

2) Look into Laravel Passport as a commenter above suggested.

This would be the preferred method, especially if you plan on consuming your API from multiple platforms.